# Boot2Docker Start up fails

Tags: virtual-machine, docker

I am completely new to docker. I have installed it from [Source](https://github.com/boot2docker/windows-installer/releases/tag/v1.4.1). I am trying to run it from cmd by using `boot2docker start`. But i get the following

```
boot2docker start
     Failed to start machine boot2docker-vm <run again with v for details> 

boot2docker init
     virtual machine boot2docker-vm already exists

boot2docker start
     Failed to start machine boot2docker-vm exit status:1
```

So, For you guys it would be a simple one. I don't know what to do. I tried [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26572112/running-boot2docker-error-in-run-failed-to-get-machine-boot2docker-vm-mac). But i can't able to understand the solution so i failed to achieve it. Please provide some suggestions

EDIT:
   I hope it will be helpful. There is some thing disabled in bios.

```
boot2docker -v start
Boot2Docker-cli version: v1.4.1
Git commit: 43241cb
2014/12/18 16:12:35 executing: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe
  showvminfo boot2docker-vm --machinereadable
2014/12/18 16:12:35 executing: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe
  guestproperty set boot2docker-vm /VirtualBox/GuestAdd/SharedFolders/MountPrefix
  /
2014/12/18 16:12:36 executing: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe
  guestproperty set boot2docker-vm /VirtualBox/GuestAdd/SharedFolders/MountDir /
2014/12/18 16:12:36 executing: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe
  sharedfolder add boot2docker-vm --name c/Users --hostpath C:\Users --automount
  VBoxManage.exe: error: Shared folder named 'c/Users' already exists
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code VBOX_E_OBJECT_IN_USE (0x80bb000c), componen
  t SessionMachine, interface IMachine, callee IUnknown
  VBoxManage.exe: error: Context: "CreateSharedFolder(Bstr(name).raw(), Bstr(hostp
  ath).raw(), fWritable, fAutoMount)" at line 1009 of file VBoxManageMisc.cpp
  2014/12/18 16:12:36 executing: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe
  setextradata boot2docker-vm VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/ c/U
  sers 1
2014/12/18 16:12:36 executing: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe
  startvm boot2docker-vm --type headless
  Waiting for VM "boot2docker-vm" to power on...
VBoxManage.exe: error: **VT-x is disabled in the BIOS.** (VERR_VMX_MSR_VMXON_DISABLE
  D)
VBoxManage.exe: error: D**etails: code E_FAIL (0x80004005)**, component Console, int
  erface IConsole
2014/12/18 16:12:38 executing: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe
  showvminfo boot2docker-vm --machinereadable
error in run: Failed to start machine "boot2docker-vm": exit status 1
```

Comment: I had similar things happen on the Mac, and solved it by launching the boot2docker vm with Virtualbox.

Comment: boot2docker delete; boot2docker download; boot2docker init; fixed this issue for me on a Mac.

Answer (score 6):

### Cause:

The nugget of info you need to pay attention to in your error log is

```
  Waiting for VM "boot2docker-vm" to power on...
  VBoxManage.exe: error: **VT-x is disabled in the BIOS.**(VERR_VMX_MSR_VMXON_DISABLE
  D)
```

This means that your current workstation's BIOS settings is preventing virtualization of another operating system on your CPU.  Docker runs a virtual linux OS on your machine, so this is the issue.

For Intel chips, virtualization features are usually called VT-x or something like that.  For AMD chips, virtualization features are called AMD-V.  I use an Intel chip like you though, so this solution pertains to Intel chips.

### Solution:

Power down and go into your BIOS and enable VT-x.  In my BIOS, a Lenovo Thinkpad T440, the setting that needs to be changed was under Security->Virtualization.

Power up and go back to your `C:/path/to/Boot2Docker for Windows` folder.

Run `boot2docker delete` to ensure no VMs are running.

Run `boot2docker init` to initialize the VM.

Run `boot2docker start` to create a new Docker Virtual Machine!

To  get access to your Docker VM, run `boot2docker ssh` since the Docker Client doesn't run on Windows as of version 1.5.0.